# Setting useSeoMeta from Async Data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this code where I fetch from my Sanity CMS. I'm looking to set the `useSeoMeta` so that the title is the title from Sanity's Data.

```
const { data } = useAsyncData('category', () => sanity.fetch(
  query, { categoryId: route.params.id }
));

useSeoMeta({
      data,
      description: () => `${data.value[0].description}`,
      title: () => `${data.value[0].title} Card Prices & List`,
});
```

The issue I have is, on first click the page does not load, then second click the page loads with the title/description loaded in. On first click, I get the usual `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')` on data as it hasn't been loaded in yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a placeholder while it loads

```
const { data } = useAsyncData('category', () => sanity.fetch(
  query, { categoryId: route.params.id }
));

useSeoMeta({
      data,
      description: () => `${data.value?.[0].description ?? 'Loading...' }`,
      title: () => `${data.value?.[0].title ?? 'Loading' } Card Prices & List`,
});
```

Or you try to use top level `setup`

```
<script setup>
const { data } = await useAsyncData('category', () => sanity.fetch(
  query, { categoryId: route.params.id }
));


useSeoMeta({
      data,
      description: () => `${data.value[0].description }`,
      title: () => `${data.value[0].title } Card Prices & List`,
});

</setup>
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick, unsure if google will take that as the final title or not.

Comment: @JMKelley or you use top level setup like i showed

Comment: Unfortunately, the initial bug was within the top level `setup` that it was happening.